# Use .properties without using xml configuration in spring

Tags: java, spring

I found a way to use .properties files in spring when using Java-based Configuration and xml from [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-composing-configuration-classes) article. The illustrations is as follows. My question is "**Is there any way to use .properties files only using Java-based configuration without using xml files?**"

i.e Is there any way to omit `@ImportResource` in following code and use pure Java-based configuration?

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:/com/acme/properties-config.xml")
public class AppConfig {
   private @Value("${jdbc.url}") String url;
   private @Value("${jdbc.username}") String username;
   private @Value("${jdbc.password}") String password;

   public @Bean DataSource dataSource() {
      return new DriverManagerDataSource(url, username, password);
   }
}
```

properties-config.xml

```
<beans>
   <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/com/acme/jdbc.properties"/>
</beans>
```

jdbc.properties

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/xdb
jdbc.username=sa
jdbc.password=
```

Sample Main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
   TransferService transferService = ctx.getBean(TransferService.class);
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Probably not without a lot of extra coding ... but why bother?

Comment: Because I'm trying to use only java-based configuration

Comment: The java Properties class (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) has a `public void loadFromXML(InputStream in)` method so you can build a properties object without spring

Comment: @TheKojuEffect - that dodges the question.  Why are you trying to implement a java-only configuration?  What use-case makes use of just a little bit of XML configuration unacceptable?

Comment: @StephenC Its not about unacceptable, I prefer to use java-based configuration. Also, it seems to be possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try like this

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("/app.properties")
public class Test {
    @Value("${prop1}")
    String prop1;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer getPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

or using Environment

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("/app.properties")
public class Test {
    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new DriverManagerDataSource(env.getProperty("url"), env.getProperty("username"), env.getProperty("password"));
    }
}
```

read this article http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/ for more info

Comment: fyi, you can use any any bean post processor by using @Bean with a static method.  You can manually configure a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer this way as well (you're not just confined to the PropertySources style configuration shown above)

Comment: Oh wow.  They've fixed it at last.  Last time I used Spring in anger (3.0) you had to do "nasty" things to get property values into a bean's wiring.